# Glitch with internet explorer using a textarea and CSS font-size

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have created a js (with jQuery) to change the size of the text inside a textarea by changing the css. pressing a button the next JavaScript is called:

```
$("#id").css("font-size",fontsize + "px");
```

And it's working. but with internet explorer (at least the version 9), the text goes outside the bounds of the Textarea, but if I edit the text, it automatically is arranged.

Example:

[image: text before changing the size]
Text before changing the size

[image: text after changing the size]
Text after changing the size. **This is only happening with IE**

[image: text after edit the textarea]
Text after edit the textarea. This is the result that a get in Chrome, but for IE this only happen after edit it

For me, that's a glitch, is there any workaround to fix it?

Comment: You will find with form input fields that every browser renders them differently. This particular issue seems unusual though. Could it be related to box-sizing? What version of IE is it?

Comment: @Jackson the version is IE9

Comment: Do you have this issue only by changing the font size in javascript, or also with css ?

Comment: @Brewal The .css function of JQuery only edit the style property of the element. I'm not changing the class name, just editing the style property.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. If you comment the JS code and directly change the font size with CSS `#id {font-size: 26px}`, is the problem still there ?

Comment: if i change the css, when the page is loaded the text and the textarea is fine. if i change the css by using the IE Console, the error still happening.

Comment: Then I guess it is about the CSS rendering engine of IE9. You should try to force "redrawing" of the textarea by changing its size maybe. We can only provide a workaround.

Comment: @Brewal i've tried to redraw with this.  just re assign the value to the text area.  I really don't like this but is working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you :

```
var value=$("#id").value();
$("#id").css("font-size",fontsize + "px").replaceWith( $("#id").clone().val(value) );
```

All I am doing is re-inserting the element in the DOM. I think this is the only way to solve this annoying bug.

*Happy coding!*

Comment: Please tick the answer if I helped.

Comment: it's a possible solution but not the only way for fix it. i was able to fix it by re assigning the value. with something like this: 

$("#id").css("font-size",font size + "px").val($("#id").val());

however, your answer seem more safe because i don't know if reinserting the values work with every scenario.

Comment: That's a clever solution too. Even I am not sure that your's is safe or not. Anyway, good luck :)

Comment: I'll take this answer. but in the first line "var value=$("#id").value();", i've changed to "var value=$("#id").val();". 

Many thanks.